# Holomorphic in a unit disk based on Identity Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Given two functions $f_1(z_n)$ and $f_2(z_n)$ are holomorphic in the unit disk circle centered at the origin and $f_1(z_n)=f_2(z_n)$ for $z_n=1/n$, n=3,4,5,... Does it imply $f_1(1/2)=f_2(1/2)$?

I tried using the Identity Theorem which states that:

Given functions f and g holomorphic on a connected open set D. Specifically, if two holomorphic functions f and g on a domain D agree on a set S which has an accumulation point c in D then f = g on all of D. But how to relate it to this problem is my worry. Can someone assist me?

Comment: If $f_1\lvert_D = f_2\lvert_D$ and $1/2 ∈ D$, …

Comment: @k.stm, does it mean that Since $f_1$ and $f_2$ are holomorphic in $D$ then there exists functions $a,b,c,d$ in $D$ such that $f_1=a/b$ and $f_2=c/d$, now let $h=ad-bc$ it is a holomorphic function on $D$, and for all $z_n$ we have $h(z_n)=0$, by continuity of $h$ and the fact that $z_n\to z_0$, we get $h(z_0)=0$, hence $h=0$, so that $a/b=c/d$ i.e $f_1=f_2$?

Comment: @J.R.: Why so complicated? $z_n = 1/n$ has the accumulation point $z = 0 \in D$, therefore $f_1 \equiv f_2$ .